# How to switch to editor immediately after opening file

Tags: editor, intellij-idea

When I hit "Enter" on a file in Project View, I want my caret to be positioned right in the editor, so that I can start making changes.

Now, I am forced to close the Project View using Alt+1 or to manually click (eh) inside the editor.

Answer (score 3):

Hit <kbd>F4</kbd> or enable **Autoscroll to source** option in the Project View.

Comment: It worked in PhpStorm 3+. It doesn't work in PhpStorm 4. What should I do?